# how do I convert this string value to date in python?

Tags: python, mysql

Could you please help me with how to convert the string value '6/4/2020' to date?

My CSV file's timestamp column also comes in different string values, such as

4/6/2013

12/20/2019

1/17/2020.

Comment: Did you do any research? Python has built-in functionality for parsing strings to dates.

Comment: Did you look at the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) docs?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask; what have you tried, and what isn't working? If it's homework, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL (totally independent of Python), we can convert a string to a DATE or DATETIME datatype using the `STR_TO_DATE` function, documented in the MySQL Reference Manual

as a demonstration

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '4/6/2013' ,'%m/%d/%Y') AS mydate
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date